# Time interval outside another time interval

Tags: php, date, time, strtotime

Given variables schedule interval:

```
$scheduleStart = '08:00 AM';
$scheduleEnd = '04:00 PM';
```

I want to find out if another 2 given intervals will fall outside or partially overlap that schedule interval.

For example:

example1:

```
$testStart = '06:00 AM';
$testEnd = '07:00 AM';

                        |--------- schedule -------|
           |--test --|
```

this should return false because test interval is outside the schedule interval.

example2:

```
$testStart = '04:00 PM';
$testEnd = '05:00 PM';

                       |--------- schedule -------|
                                                  |--test --|
```

similar to example 1 this should also return false because test interval is outside (and overlaps 04:00 PM) the schedule interval.

example3:

```
$testStart = '07:00 AM';
$testEnd = '10:00 AM';

                        |--------- schedule -------|
                    |--test --|
```

this should return false because test interval overlaps schedule interval.

example4:

```
$testStart = '02:00 AM';
$testEnd = '03:00 AM';

                        |--------- schedule -------|
                                       |--test --|
```

this one should return **true** because test interval is fully inside our schedule interval.

What I tried:

Converting all my intervals to unix ($today is today date):

```
$scheduleStartConvert = strtotime("$today $scheduleStart");
$scheduleEndConvert = strtotime("$today $scheduleEnd");
$testStartConvert = strtotime("$today $testStart");
$testEndConvert = strtotime("$today $testEnd");

if(($testStartConvert <= $scheduleStartConvert && $testEndConvert <= $scheduleStartConvert) ||
    ($testStartConvert >= $scheduleEndConvert && $testEndConvert >= $scheduleEndConvert)){
$schedule = 0;
} else {
$scehdule = 1;
}
```

But this will only work for example 1 and 2 and not for 3 (when there is a overlap). If possible I need a solution with pure PHP without any other libraries.

Comment: @Remy That could work too.

Answer (score 0):

First: Your condition of *example4* is wrong: You wrote

```
$testStart = '02:00 AM';
$testEnd = '03:00 AM';
```

but the image shows

```
$testStart = '02:00 PM';
$testEnd = '03:00 PM';
```

The easiest way is to code with the only way it should return `1`: Both, `$testStart` and `$testEnd` in the schedule range:

```
if(
    $testStartConvert >= $scheduleStartConvert
    && $testStartConvert <= $scheduleEndConvert
    && $testEndConvert >= $scheduleStartConvert
    && $testEndConvert <= $scheduleEndConvert
) {
    $schedule = 1;
} else {
    $schedule = 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

function `date_convert` take *time* and return an *object* of `DateTime`.

```php
function date_convert($time){
    $time = date('H:i:s', strtotime("today $time"));
    return DateTime::createFromFormat('H:i:s', $time);
}
```

function `test_in_schedule` check if the *Test* interval Within the *Schedule* interval.

```php
function test_in_schedule($scheduleS, $scheduleE, $testS, $testE){
    $s_s = date_convert($scheduleS);
    $s_e = date_convert($scheduleE);

    $t_s = date_convert($testS);
    $t_e = date_convert($testE);
    return ( (int)$s_s->format('H') <= (int)$t_s->format('H') and
             (int)$t_e->format('H') <= (int)$s_e->format('H') );
}
```

*All other tests are false, only this test is true:*

```
$scheduleStart = '08:00 AM';
$scheduleEnd = '04:00 PM';

$testStart = '02:00 PM';
$testEnd = '03:00 PM';
var_dump(test_in_schedule($scheduleStart, $scheduleEnd, $testStart, $testEnd));
//true
/*
                      $s_s                       $s_e
                        |--------- schedule -------|
                                       |--test --|
                                     $t_s      $t_e
*/
```